# Email action handlers / Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app relying on `Firebase` for online services.
It is working rather smoothly. But I would like to set a verification system for the email addresses when users sign up.

I have read this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) in order to see how that works.
The document refers to the "default action handler" and then explains how to customize.

Before possibly getting into customization, I would like first to look at this so-called "default action handler". So my question is **where do I find the "default action handler" and how do I use it?**